# proxy.config.json usage - basics understanding

Tags: angular

I use a remote service URL to retrieve data and use in my angular 6 project. Since it was producing CORS issue most times, I had to use proxy.config.json. Configuration is like below:

In angular.json, inside architect, inside serve, I gave an option like:

```
"proxyConfig":"proxy.config.json"
```

And inside proxy.config.json,

```
    {
     "/push/*":{
            "target":"https://abc.xyz.bluemix.net/",
            "secure":false,
            "logLevel":"debug",
            "changeOrigin":true

        }
}
```

While running in localhost, when any url with path as /push is visited, it automatically sets fetches data from url https://abc.xyz.bluemix.net/push/123

I need to know if there's a way to enable proxy on cloud too. Reason is that the application runs on https://sample-dev.bluemix.net due to which CORS issue occurs in absence of proxy.

The problem i face is that after these configurations, when i did a Build with a build cmd `ng build --prod` and push to cloud, when /push is visited, the response i get is the content in index.html and not the json data which am supposed to receive like how i received in local. I am thinking if it is due to directory structure.

Bottomnote: Enabling CORS headers in server end is not under my control. URLs are fake ones

Answer (score 0):

proxy.config.json is ran by dev server as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md). It's not anything that's downloaded to your web browser. For the proxying to work you'd have to run the dev server in production. Angular provides a reference for apache configuration as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) that may help you configure request forwarding to the api backend.